# Escape @ character in razor view engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, escaping

I am creating a sample ASP.NET MVC 3 site using Razor as view engine. The razor syntax starts with `@` character e.g. `@RenderBody()`. If I write @test on my cshtml page it gives me parse error

> CS0103: The name 'test' does not exist in the current context

How do I escape '@' character?

Comment: In C#, you can mark keywords with an @ to treat them as variable names rather than keywords. With all I know, it seems impossible to use reserved keywords in Razor this way.

Comment: @GrimaceofDespair the way to still mark keywords as variables is to enclose the second `@` in braces. I managed to get this working by writing it this way: `@(@new)`

Answer (score 1098, accepted):

`@@` should do it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in this case: `@RazorCodePart1 @@ @RazorCodePart2` e.g. a literal @ between two Razor code snippets.

Comment: The best solution would be using the HTML-encoded character string for the @-character: &#64;

Comment: I've got a `<style>` tag in my razor page, which has to embed an '@media {}' directive, so html encoding is not an option; only @@ works.

Comment: @WoIIe not in a URL.

Comment: It does not work. I tried all solutions at this page. None of them works for me :/

Comment: In href use @("@")

Comment: I needed the solution from @AsiriDissanayaka for the src in a script tag.

Answer (score 194):

Razor @ escape char to symbols...

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as @("@username")" />
```

or

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as @("@")username" />
```

Comment: This method seems the best as it will also work for @media css stuff, whereas the HTML entity way probably will not.

Answer (score 50):

`@Html.Raw("@")` seems to me to be even more reliable than `@@`, since not in all cases `@@` will escape.

Therefore:

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitterSite">
```

would be:

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Html.Raw("@")twitterSite">
```

Comment: And how do i use this on a huge text with several paragraphs? I have tried with ` instead of " but the result is questionable. No errors on blank rows but error on ` character.

Answer (score 43):

use `<text></text>` or the easier way `@:`

Comment: It's odd the (at sign colon) @: character sequence syntax doesn't work for me, as I try to upgrade my ASP.NET MVC 3 project to MVC4.  The exception I get is: "":" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid."

Comment: @Michael That's weird. They must have removed it in version 4.

Comment: Hi Kasper Skov, I found the @: issue was not actually related to @: at all.  It was related to unnecessarily using @Model, in a @if() {} block.  The fix was to drop the at sign on Model.  I need to avoid using @ when already in server scope.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809855/issue-migrating-mvc3-application-to-mvc4-compiler-error-message-cs1513-expe

Answer (score 30):

Instead of HTML entity I prefer the use of `@Html.Raw("@")`.

Answer (score 13):

@@ is the escape character for @ in Razor views as stated above.

Razor does however try to work out when an '@' is just an '@' and where it marks C# (or VB.Net) code. One of the main uses for this is to identify email addresses within a Razor view - it should not be necessary to escape the @ character in an email address.

Comment: I have not found a way for Razor/VB.net and using Prismjs. I tried all above for <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Antigen", New With {Key .id = item.AntigenId})" class="btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</a>

Answer (score 9):

For the question about `@RazorCodePart1 @@ @RazorCodePart2`, you need to the sequence:

```
@RazorCodePart1 @:@@ @RazorCodePart2
```

I know, it looks a bit odd, but it works and will get you the literal character '@' between the code blocks.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. I declared a variable putting my text with the @.

```
@{
   var twitterSite = "@MyTwitterSite";
}

...

<meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitterSite">
```

Comment: This was the only one working for me and being valid for Open Graph debuggers.

Answer (score 8):

Based on Terje Solem's answer, the UTF-8 code `%40` worked for me. This is the original URL I was trying to reach:

```
https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js
```

this is what worked for me in my code:

```
https://unpkg.com/%40google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js
```

Answer (score 5):

this work for me

```
<meta name="author" content="Alan van Buuren @("@Alan_van_Buuren")">
```

Or yoy can use:

```
@@Alan_van_Buuren
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the options above and none worked. This is what I did that worked :

```
@{
    string str = @"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$";
}

<td>Email</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id="txtEmail" required name="email" pattern=@str /> 
</td>
```

I created a string varible and passed all the RegEx pattern code into it, then used the variable in the html, and Razor was cool with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @@ for this purpose.
Like `var email = firstName + '\@@' + domain;`

Comment: This repeats multiple answers

Answer (score 1):

just add a variable in CSHTML file

```
var myVariable = @"@";
```

and add it to your layout

```
<span class="my-class"><a href="@myVariale" target="_blank" >link text</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of these to work inside my placeholder attribute, so I used xml special character.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="fex: firstname&#64;lastname.com"/>
```

See more examples here.
https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html

Comment: My need was to add @ in meta tag. and this works fine. @@ doesn't work there.

Answer (score -1):

Actually @ should be used with the Razor syntax Keywords or to the variable/model to bind a Value.

For Eg:
if test is assigned with value 
i.e @ { var test = "ABC" }
then you can get the value by settings as @test anywhere is cshtml page in html part.
otherwise, simple use as @Html.DisplayName("test")

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think in Razor view `@Html.Raw()` is the best solution for all version and always works for me. I have added an working example cdn URL to provide clear idea.

```
 @Html.Raw("<script src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js\"></script>")
```