# Razor ViewEngine: How do I escape the "@" symbol?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, escaping, twitter-anywhere

I'm trying to output some Twitter handles in ASP.NET MVC3 in conjunction with the Twitter @Anywhere API, and I haven't been able to figure out how to actually escape the "@" symbol in a Razor view.

Does anyone know what the syntax is for escaping the "@" character in Razor?

I've tried using `<text></text>` and that results in a JIT error.

Comment: You can also use the HTML entity `&#64;`.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You have to use @@ to escape the @ symbol.

One important thing to notice is that you DO NOT need to escape the @ symbol when it exists within an email address. Razor should be smart enough to figure that out on its own.

Comment: <a href="" title="this @@ won't work"></a>, both syntax error in VS and parser error in runtime.

Comment: @Tien see the last HTML character code here worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13584640/84206

Answer (score 33):

If you are adding Twitter meta tags

and your Twitter username is, say, `foobar`

it should look like this

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content=@("@foobar")>
```

Answer (score 20):

if you need to comment @ symbols in css code and just @@ wont work, use this:

```
@("@@font-face"){ ... css ...}
```

Comment: This is the best method as the HTML entity isn't helpful inside CSS.

Answer (score 4):

I had yet another odd case: pass `'@' + @Model.SomeProperty` to a link href.

The best solution for this case was given IMO in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14583891/4419939) to a similar question. Both `@@` and `@:` didn't work while using the html code `&#64;` would complicate things.

So, my code was `<a href="~/path/?query=@('@')@Model.SomePropery">`

`@Html.Raw('@')@Model.SomePropery` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding Schema.org JSON-LD Tags, @Matt's answer worked for me:

```
  ....
  @("@context"): "https://schema.org",
  ....
```