# Using a jQuery selector that uses the '@' symbol in an MVC3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, selector

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[@name='paymenttype']").change(function(){
        if ($("input[@name='paymenttype']:checked").val() == 'deposit') {
            //Display deposit form.
        }
        else if ($("input[@name='paymenttype']:checked").val() == 'creditcard') {
            // Display credit card form.                
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, the Razor view engine is catching my `@` symbol.

Is there some way to tell it to ignore that specific instance of the `@` symbol?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287704/razor-viewengine-how-do-i-escape-the-symbol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `@` in those selectors.
This syntax has been deprecated since jQuery 1.2, and it was removed in 1.3.

To answer your questions, you can output a literal `@` by writing `@@`, or you can move that code to an external (non-Razor) `.js` file.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ Just remove the `@`.