# avoiding special characters in asp.net mvc with razor engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp mvc application. in a view i have this snippet:

```
@Html.Label(admin.Mail)
```

The result is false because of the special caracter `@`. So how can i avoid this error and read exactly the label?

Comment: What the error that you get?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287704/razor-viewengine-how-do-i-escape-the-symbol

Comment: For example if i have this mail `xxxx@gmail.com` the label shown is `com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the email address, Use `DisplayFor` html helper method.

If Mail is a property of the Model passed, You can do it like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Mail)
```

If `Mail` is a property of of a sub collection of your model, you can display it like this

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Contacts)
{
    <div> @Html.DisplayFor(s=>i.Mail)</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how do you escape `@` in Razor, the way to do it is `@@`.

Or you can try to write just the text-> something like `<label>@admin.Mail</label>`

**EDIT**

You can also give this a shot:

```
@Html.Display(admin.Mail)
```

Comment: You mean `@@Html.Label(admin.Mail)` or `@Html.Label(@admin.Mail)`. twice give me a fault result

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text with `<text></text>` tags, for example `<text>mail@gmail.com</text>`