# how How to use @ in external html file on asp.net mvcresource url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, arcgis-js-api, cedar

I created a chart by using [CedarCharts](https://github.com/esri/cedar) in a separate `.html` file and after that I placed this file in my ASP.NET project's `.cshtml` file. But some libraries are used for this chart and it uses the `@` symbol and my `.cshtml` file considers it as an mistake/error.

These are some libraries

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@esri/arcgis-rest-request"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@esri/arcgis-rest-feature-service"></script>
```

How can I remove error on `@` from my razor `.cshtml` file.

This is [expected output](https://codepen.io/tomwayson/pen/paxgeO?editors=0010).

Comment: It looks like the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287704/razor-viewengine-how-do-i-escape-the-symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways

```
@Html.Raw("<script src='https://unpkg.com/@esri/arcgis-rest-request'></script>")
```

or

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@("@esri")/arcgis-rest-request'></script>
```