# Populating a drop down list with non-repeating values

Tags: sql, drop-down-menu, webmatrix

I have a multiple search query which includes a drop down to pick an admin which needs to be called from the Assigned_To column in my RMS db. The problem is that the dropdown shows every single value repeated. For example:

**Admin:**
Not assigned
Not assigned
"
"
"
Alexandra M.
Martin D.
Alexandra M.

I want it to look like:

**Admin:**
Not assigned
Martin D.
Alexandra M.

"Not assigned" is the default value of a case that is created.

Here is my code:

```
var db = Database.Open("RMS") ;

var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM RMS";
var formSSO = "";
var formAssigned_To = "";
var formCase_Status= "";
var fromDate = "";
var toDate = "";

    formSSO = Request.QueryString["formSSO"];
    formAssigned_To = "%" + Request["formAssigned_To"] + "%";
    formCase_Status = Request["formCase_Status"];
    fromDate = Request.QueryString["fromDate"];
    toDate = Request.QueryString["toDate"];

    selectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM RMS WHERE 1=1";

if(!Request.QueryString["formSSO"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND SSO LIKE @0";
}

if(!Request.QueryString["formAssigned_To"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Assigned_To LIKE @1";
}

if(!Request.QueryString["formCase_Status"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Case_Status = @2";
}

if(!Request.QueryString["fromDate"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Created >= @3";
}


if(!Request.QueryString["toDate"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Created <= @4";
}



var data = db.Query(selectCommand, formSSO, formAssigned_To, formCase_Status, fromDate, toDate);
var columns = new[]{"ID", "SSO", "Category", "System", "Subject", "Created", "Assigned_To"};
var grid = new WebGrid(data, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", defaultSort: "ID", columnNames: columns);
if (Request.QueryString[grid.SortDirectionFieldName].IsEmpty()) {
grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
}
}
```

And this is the html form field for the dropdown:

```
<li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_22">
<label class="form-label-top" id="label_22" for="input_22"> ADMIN </label>
<div id="cid_22" class="form-input-wide">       
<select name="formAssigned_To">
 @foreach(var row in data){
        <option></option>
        <option value="@row.ID">@row.Assigned_To</option>
    }
    </select>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I changed my form field to this: (Which has its own SELECT DISTINCT because it was specific to this field.

```
       <li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_22">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_22" for="input_22"> ADMIN </label>
        <div id="cid_22" class="form-input-wide">       
        <select name="formAssigned_To">
        <option></option>
        @foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT Assigned_To FROM RMS")){
        <option value="@row.Assigned_To">@row.Assigned_To</option>
         }
        </select>
        </div>
        </li>
```

I left my selectCommand like this:

```
selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM RMS WHERE 1=1";
```

This was thanks to: [CSHTML - SQL QUERY....WHERE NAME=@NameOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796730/cshtml-sql-query-where-name-nameone)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use 
    `SELECT DISTINCT Assigned_To FROM RMS WHERE 1=1`

That would give you the distinct values for the dropdown, otherwise you would have to do it 
from the returned results.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not working for me :/ I think it is because of my conditions.