# validating email address using regular expression on razor page

Tags: javascript, regex, razor

Hi I am using razor and trying to use regular expression to validate email address here the validation function

```
function validateEmail(txtEmail){
   var a = document.getElementById(txtEmail).value;
   var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{0,4}$/;
    if(filter.test(a)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}​
```

but since the regular expression has a @ sign razor thinks it part of it syntax and gives me an error.

Is there anyway to avoid to make sure razor disregards @ sign in JavaScript

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when someone turns off javascript on your site?

Comment: See [Escape @ character in razor view engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine). Alternatively you can put Javascript in a separate file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unicode may work like this

```
string filter = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\\u0440[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{0,4}$/";
```

Alternatively in razor @@ is a normal @ symbol, it should work in your javascript.

```
string filter = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{0,4}$/";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be help you

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^[_a-z0-9-A-Z-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-A-Z-]+)*@[a-z0-9-A-Z-]+(\.[a-z0-9-A-Z-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is common to check the format of the email is valid or not. To validate email address we need to use regular expression. In MVC razor we should use @@ symbol to perform validation.
[MVC razor:](http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-check-client-side-validation-for-email-address-using-JavaScript-in-asp-net-MVC/1157)

var emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:\s@@\"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:\s@@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

Normal Html:

For normal we should use @ symbol to perform validation

var emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:\s@\"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

**for more details visit**