# use @ in script code in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape @ character in razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

how can i use '@' symbol in my script code in the MVC page (razor engine)

write a code like this :

```
<script>
var a = "this is a test text with @ symbol";

alert(a);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape by use of two ampersat symbols: `@@`.

```
var a = "this is a test text with @@ symbol";
```

As an aside, though I recently learned and think those coming across this question might also find it useful: you can do comments with a combination of ampersat signs and asterisks:

```
@*this would comment out some code, or just allow for comments in general*@
```

Answer (score 4):

`@@` should work to escape the character

Comment: thx jrummell, i'll try to use code syntax nex time !

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = "this is a test text with "+<text>@</text>+" symbol";
```

Answer (score 2):

To escape an `@` symbol you need to double it up like so:

```
@@
```