# need to put at sign in my razor based page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to have '@font-face' in my style section at my razor page.
However the at sign (@) performs a problem for the razor. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer : [Escape @ character in razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine).

You have to escape it with : `@@`

Comment: You're amazing guy. both of you. answer in less than a minute. Thank you.