# How do you escape a '@' symbol within in a url with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, escaping, umbraco, razorengine

I know this is probably going to be something very simple and it is like just a 'gotcha' that I have yet to get; however, I have been struggling with escaping the `@` symbol in the following URL.

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/@55.000000,-1.000000,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

I have already tried escaping it with a second `@` i.e.

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/@@55.000000,-1.000000,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

Yet that produces the following YSOD

[image: Parser Error Message: "55.00000" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.]
What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape @ character in razor view engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try use `&#64;` instead of an actual @

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/&#64;55.000000,-1.000000,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

Comment: Why encode it when C# has an escaping method for the symbol already? just double the symbol to @@. Which is (in my opinion) more readable.

Comment: If you read the question once more, you'll see that using @@ gives YSOD.. So this was the workaround.

Answer (score 10):

I wonder why nobody suggest using url encoded character `%40` for `@`?

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/%4055.000000,-1.000000,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

For me this works.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: @pbjork answer &#64; worked; %40 didn't, for this URL in a <link> tag in a .cshtml page: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css

Answer (score 6):

Just another way:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/@("@55.000000,-1.000000"),17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/@("@")55.000000,-1.000000,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another (may in some case better) way to escape `@`-symbols in razor templates.

In my usecase, I have a partial with assets wich should be replaced by a [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) grunt-task. When reference a scoped npm package, there is a `@` inside the path string.

```
@using Foo.Bar.Helpers

@{ 
    var somescope = "@somescope";
}

@Html.RegisterAssetBlock(
    content: @<text>
        <!-- build:js /assets/js/bundle.js -->
        <script src="/node_modules/@somescope/somepackage/dist/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--endbuild-->
    </text>
)
```

So in every case, there is the correct string (**client** compile-time and **server** compile-time).

**For your case this would mean following:**

```
@using Foo.Bar.Helpers

@{
    var location = "@55.000000,-1.000000";
}

<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/@(location),17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e736c74d13649:0xe560f3b38693aec3">View on Google Maps</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix for this is to use `@@` instead of `@`.
This is the way MS recommends to escape a single `@`.