# MVC Razor view retain @

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've a code like below on razor where we need @videoPlayer is actually a string and would like to retain as it is.

```
<param name="@videoPlayer" value="@model.id" />
```

At the moment razor view thinks that @videoPlayer is the variable and tries to convert.

How do I retain and out put as it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape @ character in razor view engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with this code

```
<param name="&#64;videoPlayer" value="&#64;model.id" />
```

It would be rendered at HTML once it is sent back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

use a double '@' symbol

```
<param name="@@videoPlayer" value="@model.id" />
```