# How can I escape @ under Razor page when working with JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning `AngularJS` and came up with this issue:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm">
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="ctrl.user.username"
           ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/"
           ng-required="true"
           ng-minlength="4">
    <input type="password"
           ng-model="ctrl.user.password"
           ng-required="true">
    <input type="submit"
           value="Submit"
           ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

In the statement `"ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/"` I wanted to use `'@'` but I can not. I have tried `@@` but it's also not working. It's giving me this error:

> "[" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers,
>   keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfICXk

Comment: are you really utilizing any viewModel on page?, if no then convert it to html page...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape @ character in razor view engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way would be:

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@("@")[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use double '`@@`' or declare a string variable assign the pattern and use. like this,

```
@{
   string tempstr = "/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/";
}
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm">
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="ctrl.user.username"
           ng-pattern="@tempstr"
           ng-required="true"
           ng-minlength="4">
    <input type="password"
           ng-model="ctrl.user.password"
           ng-required="true">
    <input type="submit"
           value="Submit"
           ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

Hope it helps, thanks.