# Escaping @ in property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to add an pattern for my email input field:

```
<input type="email" size="1" required="" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$">
```

escaping with @@ does not work work

```
<input type="email" size="1" required="" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$">
```

This does always give me the following exception:

> "[" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

please note that the input is within a @if { } block.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Are you sure you need to escape it in this case? We do this all the time (admittedly I don't recall if it's in an `@if` block) but we don't need to escape the "@" in those cases.

Comment: You can use the html encoding `&#64;` as it mentions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine/13584640#13584640

Comment: @Craig if I dont escape it, I am getting the same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses to the rescue! Any time there’s an ambiguity in Razor, you can use parentheses
to be explicit about what you want:

```
<input type="email" size="1" required="" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@("@")[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$">
```