# @angular and ASP.NET Razor @

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, angular

I'm working through angular's upgrade tutorial to use the UpgradeAdaptor to run my angular 1 app side by side with angular 2. I am running into an issue where importing the @angular packages is clashing with the @ that Razor uses.  The first place I found this issue is when importing the UpgradeAdaptor:

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';
```

I was able to get around that by changing it to `@@angular/upgrade`, but i feel like there has to be a better way.  I know I'm going to be using the **@** symbol a lot with angular 2 and don't want to have to do @@ each time.

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` method ?

Comment: Having to have it as a string seems like an even worse approach. Thanks though.

Comment: Here is a list of solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine#3626870