# "$" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error when I'm putting the ng-pattern. Why is that?

```
<input type="password" required ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/"
```

and how to put a error message when it's not valid pattern, is this right?

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="f1.Password.$error.pattern">
    Invalid Pattern
</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape @ character in razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use easy way to validate your password here:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm" style="padding-top:30px; margin-left:30px"> 
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="formData.password" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/" required />
    <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required && myForm.password.$dirty">required</span>
    <span ng-show="!myForm.password.$error.required && (myForm.password.$error.minlength || myForm.password.$error.maxlength) && myForm.password.$dirty">Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.</span>
    <span ng-show="!myForm.password.$error.required && !myForm.password.$error.minlength && !myForm.password.$error.maxlength && myForm.password.$error.pattern && myForm.password.$dirty">Must contain one lower &amp; uppercase letter, and one non-alpha character (a number or a symbol.)</span>
    </br></br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Here is the working Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/f09GAGbSKAof3ORm8g5x