# Regular Expression error in visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, expression

[image][image]    var regex =/^([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w]+.)*\w[\w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

Errors :

> \ "unexpected character"
>
> ? "invalid expression term "
>
> w "the name does not exist in the current content"

The above one is showing error as below

[image]

Comment: \ is showing as an unexpected character
? is showing "invalid expression term "

Comment: and also shows "the name 'w' does not exist in the curent content"

Comment: OK thank you so much

Comment: `[\w]+` seems unnecessary. Try making it `\w+` instead.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: still error showing

Comment: Perhaps you're using a language where `@` is interpreted as a special character. Try escaping `@` with `\@`.

Comment: that works fine but remaining place error showing

Comment: What "place error" do you mean?

Comment: please see the image i have attached now

Comment: You need to [escape the `@`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700858/884561) because the Razor engine is picking that up as C#/VB.NET code.

Comment: @Baktha Is that regex for Email Validation?

Comment: Yes it is for email validation

Comment: I removed @ symbol and tried. After enter exmple@gmail.com  send button is not focusing. It shoud focus when I enter third letter of "com"

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: @Baktha I see your image but it appears that you're still not escaping `@`. Try making it `\@` instead.

Comment: @blhsing Please see the recent image. I have added. But still error

Comment: @KennethK. It is working with @ symbol in notepad++ but not in Visual Studio

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you use regular expression in a model class then to this way. I use regular expression in my model class as a seen below:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [RegularExpression(@"\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b", ErrorMessage = "example@gmail.com like this pattern")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Follow this method if match your requirment