# How do I escape quotes inside attribute in razor pages

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I'm trying to pass two strings as parameters for constructor which is already embedded inside attribute with double quotes:

```
 <select asp-for="Employee.StockId" asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.Stocks, "Id", "Name")" class="form-control"></select>
```

I've tried escaping with backslashes or `@` but still no success.

**Edit:**
So, there are two options which actually worked:

```
asp-items='@new SelectList(Model.Stocks, "Id", "Name")'
asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.Stocks,@{"Id"}, @{"Name"})"
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine

Have you tried `@@` ?

Comment: @Symon yes, I tried. I think It's the wrong case there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
asp-items='@new SelectList(Model.Stocks, "Id", "Name")'
```

Comment: First one is not valid but the second is. Actually I found out that `@{"Id"}, @{"Name"}` also works.