# vertical line in the asp net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It seems I cannot use vertical line in the asp net core 3.1.3 MVC if it contains "User.IsInRole("Admin")"

For example.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a> |
}
```

The first error message is

```
Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term '|'
```

Any ideas how should I fix it?

Comment: Why do you think you can't use them? What behavior do you see? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry I added the error message.

Comment: Clearly it's treating your pipe symbols as C# code rather than HTML. Have you looked at how to force Razor to treat some text as HTML rather than C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two ways** to implement "|" in the @module:

1.Use `ASCII character(&#124;)` instead of "|"：

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> &#124;
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>  &#124;
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a> &#124;
}
```

2.Add `'@'` character before "|" with brackets：

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> @("|")
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>  @("|")
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>@("|")
}
```

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine).