# @ (at) symbol in script link is causing exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to add a link to .js file in `Pages/_Layout.cshtml` However I am getting following exception:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  CS0103  The name 'antv' does not exist in the current
> context   Blazing C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Blazing\Blazing\Pages_Layout.cshtml   31

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazingDiary.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <base href="~/" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="BlazingDiary.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()

  <div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
      An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
      An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
  </div>

  <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@antv/g2plot@1.1.28/dist/g2plot.js"></script>
  <script src="_content/AntDesign.Charts/ant-design-charts-blazor.js"></script>
  <link href="_content/AntDesign/css/ant-design-blazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="_content/AntDesign/js/ant-design-blazor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problems is in this particular link `https://unpkg.com/@antv/g2plot@1.1.28/dist/g2plot.js`. Was googling for couple of hours without success. Any ideas?

Comment: The `@` is a special character in razor syntax. You will need to escape it with another `@`. i.e. ` <script src="https://unpkg.com/@@antv/g2plot@@1.1.28/dist/g2plot.js"></script>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape @ character in razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

Comment: @phuzi - but why does it have to be escaped?

Comment: I thought "The @ is a special character in razor syntax." would have explained it... This is how a `.cshtml` page is interpreted by ASP.Net. Just like `@RenderBody` earlier. Why do you think you don't need to?

Comment: @phuzi : You don't have to (shouldn't) escape it in .net6. So it's a bug.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Did I miss something, didn't see where OP said they were using ASP.Net Core 6

Comment: He is definitely not using 6. I interpret the difference between 5 and 6 as a bug fix. I don't think razor should process src attributes in a cshtml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved in .net 6.

In .net 5 (and before) the razor engine appears to stick its nose where it doesn't belong. Luckily there is an easy fix, escape the `@` as `@@`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@@antv/g2plot@1.1.28/dist/g2plot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it still outputs a Parser Error

Comment: Well, ask a new question. Be sure to document your case precisely, best is a [mre]