# Javascript Email Checker in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Basically I am trying to have a text box that upon change it checks if a valid email is in place and if so the form is submitted for the user.  I would like to improve the regex too to only allow a specific domain but I can't get any regex to work due to every time I use a @ sign it thinks I am trying to use C# code I looked it up and supposedly adding a : fixes it but it hasn't for me and I tried a ; too.

```
document.getElementById("txtCallerID").onchange = function () {
        var temp = document.getElementById("txtCallerID").value

        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(temp))
          {
            this.document.submit();
          }
    }
```

and here is a picture with the error.
[image]

Have now also tried adding a backslash before the @ to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Are you using visual studio? and in what type of file is this saved?

Comment: Yes I am using visual studio to run / edit sometimes with a mix of visual studio code on editing.  This is a ASP.net website and this is currently in the main index.cshtml view.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely escape the `@` symbol with a backslash so it's only recognised as  a regex literal. Here is how you would do this...

Change: `@` to `\@`

Fixed regex literal: `/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*\@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/`

Comment: Didn't work it still shows the same error

Comment: Could you try wrapping the "\@" with parenthesis? Like: "(\@)" ignoring quotes

Comment: (\@\ ) and \ (@) \ (no spaces stack just doesnt show without them) didn't work either this been troubling me for 2 days now xD

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help. Good luck with fixing this annoying issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
To escape the `@` sign in cshtml use `@@`.

For more info, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine).