# How can I stop razor pages from seeing an @ symbol in a script url as a C# call?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am trying to build a website using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages using bootstrap 5.
However it sees the @popperjs tag in the footer as a C# method call.
This script is the Index.cshtml file.

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

It is the first @ in this line that is bugging out.

How do I solve this issue?

ps: full index markup if needed.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- place navbar here -->
  </header>
  <main>

  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- place footer here -->
  </footer>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried both removing and duplicating the at fault @ symbol to try and escape this method call.
Neither worked.

Comment: It looks like the at character has to be escaped with @@. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine

Comment: As I stated above, @@ did not work. Error when trying: Invalid URL. The URL structure is /npm/package@version/file.js

Comment: The `@` symbol should not cause problems in URLs when they are in double-quoted strings as part of an HTML element attribute., unless the string is broken before or after the `@` symbol. You should not need to escape them or encode them.

Comment: I've opted to instead use a different cdn:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-6UofPqm0QupIL0kzS/UIzekR73/luZdC6i/kXDbWnLOJoqwklBK6519iUnShaYceJ0y4FaiPtX/hRnV/X/xlUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using @Philippe 's link.
Namely:

`@{ var FRazor = "cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/…"; } <script src=@FRazor integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>`
I hope this can help someone else hitting their head against this