# Razor double @@ symbol syntax isn't recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Visual Studio 2022 v17.7 I can't seem to get my cshtml files to understand the @@ escape syntax for the @ symbol

[image]

It's a .net 4.8 project, is there something I'm missing? Surely it's not just a CORE cshtml feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape @ character in razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine)

Comment: @@ doesn't seem to work (as seen in the image), I haven't a clue why.  It's a 4.8 framework project, is that a newer language feature or something?

Comment: Show full markup context, please. I found it works fine in the ASP.NET MVC (Framework).